# How can I make IntelliJ to show the class variable names even while not hard coding the values

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When creating an object in IntelliJ, I want the IDE to show me the class variables prompt even when I am not adding hard coding a value. The default behavior is to show only while hard coding a value. How can I make IntelliJ show me the variables at all times:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure parameter hint options at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inlay Hints | Java | Editor | Inlay Hints | Java | Parameter Hints.

Try enabling the checkboxes and check the Exclude list.

[image: Parameter hints]

Comment: This option has a lot of helpful other hints but unfortunately not the one I am looking for...

Comment: @AnudeepAnanth feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.